# Use Correct Ruby Version(rvm) with Capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano

I am trying to deploy a rails site with capistrano. I have 2 rails sites on the server, one uses ruby 2.1.2 and this capistrano one is using 2.2.2. When I run "cap production deploy" I get the following error...

```
[93a28357]  Your Ruby version is 2.1.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@mysite.com: bundle exit status: 18
bundle stdout: Your Ruby version is 2.1.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2
bundle stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 18
bundle stdout: Your Ruby version is 2.1.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2
bundle stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bundler:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@mysite.com: bundle exit status: 18
bundle stdout: Your Ruby version is 2.1.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2
bundle stderr: Nothing written
```

On my "deply.rb" file I have the following...

```
set :rvm_ruby_string, :local
```

gems used...

```
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.4.0'
gem 'capistrano-rvm', '~> 0.1.2'
gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1.4'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.3'
gem 'capistrano3-unicorn', '~> 0.2.1'
```

Comment: Do you have the `ruby "x.y.z"` in your gemfile?

Comment: Yeah on my Gemfile I have: ruby '2.2.2'

Comment: You're uploading a Gemfile, where you're specifying ruby version 2.2.2, onto a machine that you explicitly want to use 2.1.2. This will never work. You should consider removing the ruby declaration from your Gemfile, and leaving that up to the environment.

Comment: It works when I remove 'ruby '2.2.2'' from my Gemfile. But now it's using ruby 2.1.2, I'm using 2.2.2 locally and want to use 2.2.2 on production server also, how can I get it to use 2.2.2?

Comment: From the error output, the server doesn't know about ruby 2.2.2. Have you installed it there? And have you set it as the default ruby version for the env in which the app is running?

Comment: Yes I have it installed via rvm(I can run rvm use 2.2.2 on server and it runs 2.2.2). But server runs 2.1.2 by default. If I set 2.2.2 as default, my other app running 2.1.2 would need to use 2.2.2 also? How can I have 2 apps running 2 separate versions is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You should take a look at this configuration option for rvm: https://rvm.io/workflow/projects

Answer (score 0):

```
set :rvm_ruby_string, '2.2.2'
```

Add above line and it works for you